# Specifying the sources of many unioned COUNT-statements

Tags: sql, oracle, union

My objective is to count the number of records associated with three tables and combine the results into one another. However, it seems `UNION` automatically orders the result, so there is no way to know which result is from which table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_CHILD
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_child.cust_id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_ADULT
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_adult.cust_id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_ELDER
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_elder.cust_id

/* Results in: */
COUNT(*)
    0
    3
    4
```

Two possible solutions come to mind:

- Adding a column with the table names or just some string
- Showing the results in some different, possibly matrix form

They would look something like this:

```
Name  | COUNT(*)    Child | Adult | Elder    Child | Adult | Elder
----------------    ---------------------    ---------------------
Child | 3             3       4       0        3       0       0
Adult | 4                                      0       4       0
Elder | 0                                      0       0       0
```

I tried to rename each result `COUNT(*) as "Child"` and so on to achieve the middle, but it just produced a single column named `Child`.

So I have no idea how these might be achieved, I'm quite new to SQL. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `UNION` -- unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

SQL result sets are *unordered*, unless you have an explicit `ORDER BY`.  So, don't depend on the ordering and include a column that says what the number is for:

```
SELECT 'child' as which, COUNT(*)
FROM ACTM JOIN
     CUS_CHILD
     ON actm.cust_id = cus_child.cust_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'adult' as which,  COUNT(*)
FROM ACTM JOIN
     CUS_ADULT
     ON actm.cust_id = cus_adult.cust_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'elder' as which, COUNT(*)
FROM ACTM JOIN
     CUS_ELDER
     ON actm.cust_id = cus_elder.cust_id;
```

You can also make these subqueries and simply do:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ACTM JOIN
            CUS_CHILD
            ON actm.cust_id = cus_child.cust_id
       ) as num_child,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ACTM JOIN
             CUS_ADULT
             ON actm.cust_id = cus_adult.cust_id
       ) as num_adult,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ACTM JOIN
             CUS_ELDER
             ON actm.cust_id = cus_elder.cust_id
       ) as num_elder
FROM dual;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, which duplicates are removed in this case?

Comment: @Felix : This definitely should be the best  answer not the other.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I "definitely" am not convinced of that. But given an explanation, I might agree. So: why?

Comment: @Felix : Read the very first line from Gordon carefully and compare it with  other answer, using `UNION` is the first thing anyone arriving here seeking an answer should avoid.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes, and that was my question above: which duplicates are removed? I can't accept that it's a bad thing if, from what I gather, there only is 3 members to the result set in total.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Though I see why unioning huge sets could be undesirable.

Comment: @Felix : Do refer my comments to  that answer. I won't persuade you much, it's all  your discretion  :-)

Comment: @Felix . . . The duplicates that would be removed (in your query) are any two counts that have the same value.  The point, though, is that you should not incur the overhead of removing duplicates unless you really want to remove them.  So `union` is something that can produce the wrong answer and it incurs unnecessary overhead.  Seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Now I understand! Yeah, seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       'Child' as Name FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_CHILD
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_child.cust_id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       'Adult ' FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_ADULT
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_adult.cust_id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*),
       'Elder' FROM ACTM JOIN CUS_ELDER
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_elder.cust_id
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CUS_CHILD.cust_id is not null 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Child ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cus_adult.cust_id is not null 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Adult  ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cus_elder.cust_id is not null 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Elder  
FROM ACTM 
LEFT JOIN CUS_CHILD
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_child.cust_id
LEFT JOIN CUS_ADULT
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_adult.cust_id
LEFT JOIN CUS_ELDER
    ON actm.cust_id = cus_elder.cust_id
```

Comment: Uh.. Simple, elegant. I love it! And the second one is good to know as well. Thanks!

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN CUS_CHILD.cust_id is not null 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)`  is same as `COUNT(CUS_CHILD.cust_id)` and much efficient.

Comment: As for the union all I also agree I just left it as yours, Regurding the second solution - probably more correct and better in terms of performance since it passes the table only one time!.